# React: receiving Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child, when trying to render an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm working with React 16 and my goal I'm trying to render an array from a JSON file, I'll appreciate any help.

**JSON:** trying to render a list of `codigoLote`

```
{ 
"_id" : "bMv7ip59zuy3PyTvD", 
"codigo" : "001", 
"name" : "Nombre 1", 
"lab" : "Lab 2", 
"principio" : "activo", 
"dosis" : "dos", 
"sintomas" : "tres", 
"contra" : "cuatro", 
"createdAt" : ISODate("2017-11-05T19:12:19.628Z"), 
"Lotes" : [
{ "codigoLote" :"B4578", "cantidad" : "100", "costo" : "0.00", 
  "fIngreso" : "7/11/2017", "fVence" : "7/11/2017" }

{ "codigoLote" :"B4579", "cantidad" : "100", "costo" : "0.00", 
  "fIngreso" : "7/11/2017", "fVence" : "7/11/2017"}
 ] }
```

I tried this but React won't render it with this error: *Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {codigoLote, cantidad, costo, fIngreso, fVence}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

```
<Row>
    {this.props.meds.Lotes}
</Row>
```

I tried this solution as well, but it doesn't seem to find my the fields on the array.

```
  var ListRender = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <ul>
          {this.props.meds.Lotes.codigoLote(function(listValue){
            return <li>{listValue}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
      )
    }
  });

. . .

<Row>
    <ListRender />
</Row>
```

Comment: Why are you using `React.createClass` if you're using React 16?

Answer (score 2):

What are you expecting the end result to be? You have an array of objects. You need to loop through that array of objects, then for each object, look through *him* and spit out each key-value pair as an `<li>` formatted however you want. Maybe something like:

```
  <ul>
    {this.props.meds.Lotes.map((lotesObject) => (
      Object.entries(lotesObject).map(([key, value]) => (
        <li>{key}: {value}</li>
      ))
    ))}
  </ul>
```

---

*Edit:* You'd actually probably be better off making each object his own `<ul>`, plus whatever else you may wanna do inside:

```
  <div>
    {this.props.meds.Lotes.map((lotesObject) => (
      <ul>
        {Object.entries(lotesObject).map(([key, value]) => (
          <li>{key}: {value}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ))}
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried the above but it comes back with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. I'm a bit lost here, how should I initialize it?

Comment: Why is `this.props.meds.Lotes` ever undefined? Is the data being returned by an API at some point and possibly not loaded yet?